# Problems with understanding communication pattern "Preference Key" in SwiftUI

Tags: design-patterns, swiftui

*UPDATE - I have updated the entire question, since I had the feeling my presentation of the problem was very poor!*

---

I've literally just started to play around with **SwiftUI** so please excuse if this question is stupid. I'm trying since days, read many different posts and tried to follow the official documentation on apple.com but unfortunately can't get my head around how **Preference Keys** work in SwiftUI.

Basically my test-application ist structured in 3 different components:

```
ContentView
// contains a form and a text field in an HStack

    ∟ FormView
      // contains the SubFormViews in a TabView

          L SubFormView
            // contains the form fields
```

What I want to achieve is an information flow from the actual form fields up to the main view which then updates the text field. From what I've read so far, it seems that `PreferenceKey` is the best option for this problem. Thus my block view looks as follows:

My **SubFormView** looks like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// --------------------
//  The preference key
// --------------------
struct FormFieldKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = FormFieldData() // <-- I initialise the values in FormFieldData

    static func reduce(value: inout FormFieldData, nextValue: () -> FormFieldData) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

// ---------------------
//  The form field data
// ---------------------
struct FormFieldData: Equatable {
    var firstName: String

    // Initialise the form fields
    init() {
        self.firstName = ""
    }
}

// -------------------------
//  The actual subform view
// -------------------------
struct SubFormView: View {
    @State private var formFields = FormFieldData() // <-- I set the state vars for this view to FormFieldData

    var body: some View {
       Form {
        TextField("First Name", text: $formFields.firstName)
            .preference(key: FormFieldKey.self, value: self.formFields)
            // If I understood right, I set the Preference Key value here.
            // The value gets overridden by formFields.
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Then, my **FormView** is:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView() {  // <-- I intend to put additional SubFormViews in different tabs

            SubFormView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Sub Form")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my **ContentView** is:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var test: FormFieldData? // <-- I'm not sure why this has to be optional

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            FormView()
                .onPreferenceChange(FormFieldKey.self) { self.test = $0 } // <-- I literally have no clue what I'm supposed to do here!
            Text("\(self.test!.firstName)") // This is what I would like to achieve
                       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm really stuck and simply can't get my head around how this works...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Injected ObservableObject as view model would be much more convenient in this scenario.

Comment: @Asperi - thank you for your answer! I had a look but 1st I could not really get it working with `ObservableObject` and 2nd I think the preferred way is doing this via `PreferenceKey` *(from Child to distant Parent).*

Comment: `from Child to distant Parent` for child view states - yes, for model data... I would not, but as you wish - it is your game. ))

Comment: I'm open to anything! The problem I had with `ObservableObject` was that I do not know how to tell the *Observable* that it needs to become the value of the *TextField*. The only property I could find was `.preference`... Could you give me a hint?

Comment: from the distance your problem looks a lot like what is being done here https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-3/ and that is done with PreferencesKeys

Comment: Thank you @GrandSteph! This actually does help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that nobody can help with the original question, I was following @Asperi's comment and managed to solve the problem via `ObservableObject`. I'm still not sure if this is the *proper way of doing it* but at least it works for me know.

**SINCE I'M A TOTAL NOOB WITH SWIFTUI THIS IS OBVIOUSLY NOT A PERFECT SOLUTION (e.g. data models) BUT** just in case someone else has the same problem, here is my solution:

First I created a class **FormFields** as an `ObservableObject`.

```swift
import Foundation

class FormFields: ObservableObject {
    @Published var formData = FormData()
}

// -----------------------
// FORM DATA
// -----------------------
// Combines all data of different form blocks and makes
// it accessible throughout the app.
struct FormData {
    var block1 = Block1Data()
    // you could add as many blocks as you wish
}


// -----------------------
// BLOCK 1 DATA
// -----------------------
// Data fields for block 1. (in this case it's all Strings)
struct Block1Data {
    var firstField: String
    var secondField: String
    var thirdField: String

    // initialise form fields with empty strings (this is not essential,
    // you could also do var firstField = ""
    init() {
        self.firstField = ""
        self.secondField = ""
        self.thirdField = ""
    }
}
```

Then the **SubformView** would look like

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SubFormView: View {

    // inject the environment variable "formFields"
    @EnvironmentObject var formFields: FormFields

    var body: some View {
       Form {
        TextField("First Field", text: $formFields.formData.block1.firstField)
        TextField("Second Field", text: $formFields.formData.block1.secondField)
        TextField("Third Field", text: $formFields.formData.block1.thirdField)
       }
    }
}

// if you want your preview working for this specific sub view, don't forget
// to add the environmentObject() to the view!
struct CompanyDataFormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompanyDataFormView().environmentObject(FormFields()) // <-- this here!
    }
}
```

The **FormView** does not change since there is nothing which needs to be updated

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView() {

            SubFormView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Sub Form")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And the **ContentView** will then be

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var formFields: FormFields

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            FormView()

            Text("Output any text from the form fields now! E.g. firstField = \(formFields.formData.block1.firstField)")

        }
    }
}

// again, if you wish to see the preview then you need to attach the environmentObject
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(FormFields())
    }
}
```

**In order to get this working there is one final step which needs to be done!**

You need to set the **environment variable** in your `AppDelegate` and attach it to the `ContentView`. Here is my **AppDelegate**

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!

    // set the environment variable for the form fields
    var formFields = FormFields()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view. 
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(formFields)) // <-- attach it to ContentView
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

I hope this will safe somebody a bit of time in the development process...